# Regex pattern instead of explode

Tags: php, regex

I have a text like this:

```
NodeName: 
 nd1,
 nd2
 
 ;
 
SqlData: 

{code:java}
   select id, regexp_replace(username, '[;]+'::text, ','::text, 'g'::text) from users where id =1
{code}

    {code:java}
   select username from users where id =1
{code}
;

SqlFiles:

{code:java}
   select filename || ';'::text from users where id =1
{code}
;
```

Where can be new lines, white spaces between line etc.
I want to separate this string by ';' sign to get the following strings (with no end lines and spaces):

```
NodeName:nd1,nd2 
------ 
SqlData:{code:java}select id, regexp_replace(username, '[;]+'::text, ','::text, 'g'::text) from users where id =1{code}{code:java}select username from users where id =1{code}
------
SqlFiles:{code:java}select filename || ';'::text from users where id =1{code}
```

I cant simply use `explode` function like this:

```
$res = explode(';', $str);
```

because `';'` can be used in SQL queries inside the code tags.

So the only way I see is to use `preg_match_all` with some pattern.

I use

```
preg_match_all('\(?s)(?<=\{code:java\}).*?(?=\{code\})|.*?;\', $str, $res);
```

But it still returns 5 matches instead of 3.

Any ides how to correct pattern to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use bit more specific pattern to match the different parts and remove the newlines.

You can make use of negative lookaheads to exclude matching lines that start with a not allowed pattern and prevent the match from stopping at `{code:java}` that is not followed by a `;`

```
^(?:NodeName:\h*(?:\R(?!\h*;$).*)*|Sql(?:Data|Files):\h*\R+{code:java}(?:\R(?!{code}\R\h*;$).*)*\R{code})(?=\R+\h*;$)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternation `|`

  - `NodeName:\h*` Match *NodeName:* and optional horizontal whitespace chars
  - `(?:\R(?!\h*;$).*)*` Repeat matching all lines that do not start with optional spaces and `;` at the end of the string
  - `|` Or
  - `Sql(?:Data|Files):\h*` Match either *SqlData:* or *SqlFiles:* and optional spaces
  - `\R+{code:java}` Match a newline and *{code:java}*
  - `(?:\R(?!{code}\R\h*;$).*)*` Repeat matching all lines that do not start with *{code}* followed by a newline and `;` at the end of the string
  - `\R{code}` Match a newline and *{code}*
- `)` Close non capture group
- `(?=\R+\h*;$)` Positive lookahead, assert 1+ newlines, optional whitspace chars and `;` at the end of the string to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BSkRU7/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/l8jMg)

Example code where `$str` is the example string.

```
$re = '/^(?:NodeName:\h*(?:\R(?!\h*;$).*)*|Sql(?:Data|Files):\h*\R+{code:java}(?:\R(?!{code}\R\h*;$).*)*\R{code})(?=\R+\h*;$)/m';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
$result = array_map(function($x){
    return preg_replace("/\R+/", "", $x);
}, $matches[0]);
print_r($result);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => NodeName:  nd1, nd2 
    [1] => SqlData: {code:java}   select id, regexp_replace(username, '[;]+'::text, ','::text, 'g'::text) from users where id =1{code}    {code:java}   select username from users where id =1{code}
    [2] => SqlFiles:{code:java}   select filename || ';'::text from users where id =1{code}
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
I modified the pattern so make it more flexible for additional new lines and spaces:
^(?:NodeName:\h*(?:\R(?!\h*;$).*)*|Sql(?:Data|Files):\h*\R{0,}\s{0,}{code:java}\s{0,}(?:\R{0,}(?!{code}\R{0,}\h*;$).*)*\R{0,}{code})(?=\R{0,}\h*;$)

Comment: It's weird but for some reason the above code doesn't work the same way on
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com.
For example:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/658b54fc15c52704a8c94af8512a048fdfdd682a

Comment: Same with the pattern itself. It works perfectly on https://regex101.com/
But it doesn't work for my preg_match_all function PHP 7.0.14

Comment: @PavelP That is weird, I ran the code here with EOL versions enabled and it seems to work for versions listed https://3v4l.org/l8jMg I tested this on my machine with php 8.0.0 and it also works. Testing this on ideone. with version 7.3.5 also works https://ideone.com/sc8YLY

Comment: I copied the generated code from https://rege101.com, pasted it in sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com and got other result.
To solve my problem I change preg_match_all to preg_split
like this:    
$result = preg_split('/(?=(NodeName|SqlData|SqlFiles))/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);